# Why is Dirac delta named after Dirac when the concept was already over two centuries old?

Tags: mathematics, mathematics-social-history, dirac

Please explain why the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) function was named after Dirac, who lived in the 20th century, and what was so special about it.

I ask this because it is used in [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) which pre-dated Dirac by 200 years.  I find Green's function more insightful and so wonder why it is not called *Green's delta*.  Fourier and Cauchy are also  cited on the Wikipedia page for the Dirac delta as having used the impulse concept.

I am therefore hoping to find out what Dirac's special contribution was since the maths was already two centuries old.  I don't see this contribution on the Wikipedia page even though its implicitly referred to as Dirac's invention.

Comment: Maybe he popularized it. Very many things in mathematics are not named after the inventor but are instead named after the one who made the thing popular.

Comment: *"The Arnold Principle. If a notion bears a personal name, then this name is not the name of the discoverer. The Berry Principle. The Arnold Principle is applicable to itself"* ([source](https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.TP/~munsteg/arnold.html))

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I'd missed something that Dirac had come up with.  I think his use of it in quantum mechanics raised its profile and so his name stuck with it.

Comment: Green only predated Dirac by a century and nothing like delta function was used in Green's function, everything was phrased in terms of classical functions. Its relation to delta is only an after the fact reinterpretation produced *after* the delta function was introduced. The same goes for Fourier's, Cauchy's, etc., formulas. Delta's conceptualization as a new self-standing object was Dirac's contribution, and it turned out to be very useful in mathematics. Who came close to it before Dirac was not Green but Heaviside.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy).

Comment: Let's raise a glass to the cousin Kronecker Delta Function as well.

Comment: The WP article you cite outlines the pre-Dirac century-old history and Dirac's input. it is unclear? Have you read Dirac's book?

Comment: Please tell me the book you refer to.  I personally found it hard to understand how Wikipedia used the Dirac Delta on its page for Green's function given that Green lived before Dirac's time.  Thanks to the explanations provided I now understand that the naming convention cannot be relied on as a timeline.  I hope to learn more about Dirac but was actually focused on Green's function and like Green I am an autodidact in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of Diracs use of it in QM. After QM was a revolutionary new theory of physics and so had immense visibility because of this.

This is very similar to how Einstein popularised the study of non-Euclidean geometry by his use of such in his revolutionary theory of space and time. After all, non-Euclidean geometry had been known since Gauss's time but it simply didn't have the glamour or cachet that it began to have once Einstein arrived on the scene.