# Seeking quotes rejecting early forms of the Dirac delta

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier

Question [Why is Dirac delta named after Dirac when the concept was already over two centuries old?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/12135/why-is-dirac-delta-named-after-dirac-when-the-concept-was-already-over-two-centu) notes the Dirac delta function effectively appeared centuries before Dirac.  This was long before the now standard set theoretic notion of function was defined.  Histories tell me there was long controversy especially over Fourier's use of the integral which we now recognize as defining $\delta(x)$, which I am sure is true, but I want a quote.

I seek quotes of mathematicians who specifically rejected the uses of this idea by Lagrange, Fourier, Cauchy, etc on the grounds that it is not a function.

I do not mean people who said the delta function is not an ordinary function.  Many textbooks to this day use $\delta(x)$ more-or-less as if it were a real-valued function, while explicitly recognizing it is actually not that.  I mean people who objected to the use of $\delta(x)$, or integrals such as Fourier's which in fact define it, on those grounds.

Comment: And, of course, people should be aware that Dirac himself used much more extravagant distributions than just what we call "Dirac delta". For example, the distribution "integrate over the light cone". _That_ was a bit innovative, although already George Green c. 1828 did similar things in the context of electromagnetic stuff, as is well known.

Comment: Probably not early, but in the preface of von Neumann's Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics he says the following: "The method of Dirac ... in no way satisfies the requirements of mathematical rigor -- not even if these are reduced in a natural and proper fashion to the extent common elsewhere in theoretical physics. For example, the method adheres to the fiction that each self-adjoint operator can be put in diagonal form. In the case of those operators for which this is not actually the case, this requires the introduction of 'improper' functions with self-contradictory properties."